# sublime text right click not working for sidebar

Tags: sublime-text-2

I am using sublime text 2 on windows 7.

I had installed 3 plugins:

1. Emmet
2. Dockblockr
3. SidebarEnhancements

Now when i right click on the folders on the sidebar nothing is happening. I tried uninstalling the plugins and also tried uninstallling and reinstalling sublime text itself but still no luck.

Is there any keyborad shortcut that i can use?..Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall SidebarEnhancements and restart ST2?

Comment: yes i have tried uninstalling each of the plugins one by one and restarted but still no luck..

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue yesterday after installing phpcs, dockblockr.

1. Remove SidebarEnhancements
2. Restart ST2
3. Reinstall SidebarEnhancements

This fixed my issue.

**Edit** - After removing package check if it is removed by clicking **Preferences -> Browse Packages**, if not manually delete the folder

Comment: THANK YOU. omg I just thought sublime text 2 was broken for me... forever...

Comment: Didn't work....